# Problems with Maven default folder

Tags: maven

I'm Mohave Mac User.
I installed Maven and created project in Eclipse. Name of the project is "Mavenjava".

When I try to clean, compile, test command from Eclipse it doesn't work because it looking for a POM file in `/User/Max/`, not from `/User/Max/Mavenjava`

When I copy my POM file into `/User/Max/` - "clean" command works but I can't do "compile" and "test" commands in terminal, because I see mistake like "skip non existing resourceDirectory". 
It is still looking this files here `/Users/Max/src/main/resources`, but not in `/User/Max/Mavenjava/src/main/resoursces/`
How I could change default folders for Maven?

I spent 3 hours and don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: The location of a project is defined at first glance by the location of the pom file which should be located in `/User/Max/Mavenjava`...all other directories are within this directory for that particular project....There should never be a directory of a project in `/User/Max/` like `/User/Max/src/`...

Comment: But why it doesn’t looking for Pom file in /User/Max/Mavenjava? It is looking this file in /User/Max/

Comment: Who is looking in `/Users/Max/`? If Eclipse than you have configured / imported the project wrongly in Eclipse...I would suggest to try on command line first...

Comment: When I try to do compile and test command in terminal, why it looking my Maven project in Users/Max/ , not in /User/Max/Mavenjava ? How I could change this, because I have mistake like "No sources to compile” when it is looking in "Users/Max/"